# Swift self.performSegueWithIdentifier randomly won't work

Tags: ios, swift

In my code i have defined a function which is the delgate for actions taken on a Side menu, so when you tap the Logout action in menu `menuDelegate?.selectionDelegate(Actions.Logout)` gets executed and the function below is the delegate which handles the callback:

```
@objc func sideMenuAction(action: action) {
        if(action == .Logout){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToLogin", sender: self)
            })
        }
}
```

`9 out of 10` times this works fine and has the expected result of the user being thrown back to login view controller which has `unwindToLogin` identifier in storyboard from where ever in navigation stack they may be. but the 1 time it doesn't work, when `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` line is executed, nothing happens! no errors or warnings and when this happens the `override func prepareForSegue` isn't being called after the line gets executed!

The other thing i've noticed is that when this issue is triggered the CPU usage remains at well over 100%. The apps usual CPU usage maxs at 30%/40% for no more than 1/2 seconds.

It's difficult to reproduce and when it happens i can't figure out what's going on. Looking for some hints here to help debug possible causes.

The view hierarchy looks as following once i was able to reproduce the issue:

```
    (lldb) expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]


    <SWRevealViewController 0x12585ea00>, state: appeared, view: <SWRevealView 0x1256f3c70>
       | <demoApp.MenuViewController 0x12575daa0>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x12743e670>
       | <UINavigationController 0x126047000>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x125755270>
       |    | <demoApp.InitialViewController 0x125760050>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x1256e2b30> not in the window
       |    | <demoApp.MainViewController 0x1257f11f0>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x1257f8df0> not in the window
       |    | <demoApp.DetailViewController 0x127617250>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x1274f2280>
```

I should add that the application has two flows which impact the view hierarchy:

```
   Flow 1: User has never provided credential so Login View -> Initial View -> Main -> ......
   Flow 2: User has already logged in once so Initial View -> Main -> .......
```

The "unwindToLogin" identifier belongs to unwind IBAction of Login View controller

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you choose to use dispatch_async? Isn't the execution already happening on the main thread?

Comment: @AksharPatel I got paranoid thinking the reason why its not working is somehow at the time of execution i happen to be in a side thread and so to be on the safe side i added that to see if it fixes things. It obviously doesn't help.

Comment: You've added the view controller hierarchy. Great, so is the controller with the unwind `IBAction` (not the one you're transitioning from, but rather the one you are unwinding _to_) included in there? It's unclear from the question which view controller implemented the unwind `IBAction`.

Comment: Also, is the particular instance (confirm the actual memory address by printing `self` where you perform the unwind) of the view controller you are transitioning from also in the hierarchy?

Comment: @Rob added the details you asked for

Comment: You said "The 'unwindToLogin' identifier belongs to unwind `IBAction` of Login View controller." I don't see a `LoginViewController` in the hierarchy. The view controller class that you implemented the unwind action has to be in the hierarchy for this to work.

Comment: @Rob i think you've nailed it. In the Second flow because User has already logged in i never take him to LoginView so it's not in the navigation stack and so the unwind isn't working. How can i fix this?

Comment: You can move the `IBAction` into the `InitialViewController` and then do whatever you need to present the login view controller from there. Or make the login a modal transition and login from wherever you were. It just depends upon how you implemented the login process. But unwind segues always have to be to an `IBAction` to a view controller within the existing hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if it can't find the unwind segue `IBAction` method in any view controller in the view controller hierarchy. And that can happen for a variety of reasons. Perhaps the view controller in question is just not in the view controller hierarchy at all. Or perhaps you transitioned from one view controller to another without keeping your view controller hierarchy in sync with your view hierarchy (e.g. if you ever transitioned from one view controller to another by doing `addSubview` of one view controller's view to another, without doing the requisite `addChildViewController` call). Or perhaps you manually swapped out the root view controller somewhere. But, bottom line, some way, some how, your `IBAction` for the unwind segue just isn't found in any view controller in the existing view controller hierarchy.

The key is to first find a situation in which this happens. (I know you say it's hard to reproduce, but keep trying until your problem manifests itself.) Once you do, pause execution and look at the view controller hierarchy. For example, hit the "pause" button in your debugger (or add a breakpoint) and print the view hierarchy by enter the following at the `(lldb)` prompt if in Swift frame:

```
expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
```

Or if in Objective-C frame, simply:

```
po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]
```

For example:

[image]

Make sure your destination view controller appears in the view controller hierarchy. More than likely, it won't be there, and once you've confirmed this problem, you have to back track and figure out how the view controller in question ended up getting omitted from the view controller hierarchy. If you look at all of the view controller transitions that happen in the app, you might find one that isn't doing the standard transition.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I placed the output of the command in the original question. Does anything stand out